# Toilet flange slightly angled, options

Tags: plumbing, toilet, abs

So i must have glued the closet bend about 5 degrees off or my subfloor isn't quite level, but I'm about to install the toilet flange.

I can force it down flat and screw down the flange with a bit of effort but will this tension in the ABS be a problem long term?

Another solution with be either gluing the flange slightly crooked or heating the abs pipe to bend it slightly with a hair dryer or pouring boiling water into it.

Thoughts?

Comment: We've seen photos recently of failed ABS fittings due to such strain. I wouldn't put more than a few lbs. pressure on it. Then take Greg Hill's advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest option, assuming that the flange would not stand too high above the finished floor, is to do nothing. The wax ring used to seal between the flange and the toilet can take up quite a lot of misalignment. If the difference from the high side to the low side is less than maybe 1/4 inch (or even more, possibly) it'll be fine.

I'm not sure that a hair dryer will make enough heat to soften the ABS pipe but a hot air gun would.

It sounds like you're still in the rough construction stage where pipe replacement is simple. If so, and if the angle is really bothersome, cut it out and re-do the work. Mistakes happen and sometimes we have to re-do stuff but that's ok.

Comment: sounds like i'll be in the crawlspace tonight then. Its probably about 1/4" but I don't know about how shimming under the flange to take up the space will go before screwing down. Thanks!